# Virtuemart: Sending a set product with a variable custom-field -> Making a Free Sample Button

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, joomla3.0, virtuemart

Virtuemart 3.0.12
Joomla 3.4.8
----------------------------------------------
Disclaimer: I am rather new to both virtuemart and php, moreso php but learning.
Also as a new user, can't post photos, so they are links.

I basically need to make a 'Free Sample' Button on my products.

I have managed to figure out how to basically have a duplicate 'Add To Cart' button that adds a set 'Free Sample' product to the cart.

The problem I am having is how to add the sender products name as the custom-field value of the free sample in the cart.

I made a sublayout of the cart button and simply changed the button from sending
 $product->virtuemart_product_id to sending a set ID (3496).

```
<input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_virtuemart"/>
<input type="hidden" name="view" value="cart"/>
<input type="hidden" name="virtuemart_product_id[]" value="3496"/>
<input type="hidden" name="pname" value="Free Sample"/>
<input type="hidden" name="pid" value="3496"/>
```

I don't know if this is the best way, but it worked in sending the set product to the cart:

[Cart atm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YP9Dc.jpg)

However there is no way to know what product this came from.

-------------------------------------------------------
Example: User clicks the Free Sample button on '*Product One*', The '*Free Sample*' is added to the product with the custom field of '*Product One*' :

[required cart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ad4HP.jpg)

The Free Sample product currently has a custom string field which is empty, I was wondering if there was a way to change how the button sends the product or somesuch, to set the custom field value to that of the product.

EG: $custom_field_value == $product->product_name (I am aware this is probably very wrong but I hope it portrays my point)

I have thought of adding another  but have no idea what the variable *name* would be:

```
<input type="hidden" name="product_custom_value[]" value="<?php echo $product->product_name ?>"/>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers
Dan